# LiveEdit in Microsoft Edge (Chromium)

Tags: phpstorm, microsoft-edge, liveedit

I want to use the LiveEdit plugin for debugging my website on PhpStorm. I have configured the plugin in the settings and even downloaded the JetBrains Chrome Extension and applied to Microsoft edge. I have also allowed the extension to read and write and make changes to all and every website. Yet, I don't see LiveEdit working.

I also have applied `<all_urls>` in extension settings - no progress. What should I do?

[image: LiveEdit settings page.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for Edge in principle (as new Edge is Chromium-based), fixing [WEB-45326](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-45326) should take care of this.
For now, I'd suggest setting up Edge as a new custom browser in **Settings | Tools | Web Browsers**:

- press ***+*** to add a new browser
- use **Chrome** as a **Family**, specify a full path to browser executable as **Path**, enter a name

Browser will be available with Chrome icon in run configuration dropdown

[image]

> even downloaded the JetBrains Chrome Extension and applied to Microsoft edge

Please remove it; Chrome extension doesn't work reliably in new Chrome versions ([WEB-37230](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-37230)), and it seems that the most recent Chrome update has introduced breaking changes that made it non-functional. Since PhpStorm 2018.3 this extension is not required for debugging/Live Edit, it's not actively maintained, we plan to sunset it completely in the upcoming release

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome extension was **removed** from the store intentionally and we have no plans to bring it back.
The extension is not required for debugging since v. 2017.3; in the past couple of years, we were not recommending using it.
With Chrome 86 (released on October 6, 2020) and higher, the extension no longer works properly and we at JetBrains have no intention to update the extension to work with the new Chrome versions.
WebStorm 2020.3 removed the option to use the extension for debugging from the IDE Preferences.

Use the internal one in **Debug** mode.